# Partial view is not working correctly in mvc4?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi i have one field called contact person in my view. i kept one add button near to that field if i click that button the partial view will appear as pop-up window.

**My PartialView**

[image]
If i enter the details and click the save button it comes to the post action to save the data. Now i got 2 issues in that.

1) The Value of CustomerName will be null.

2) After i click create  button in popup window after enter the details either it have to show the same popup window or it have to show the parent view(Visitors Form)  i got issue in this step. In this place it redirect to main window of partial view. which is mentioned in below image.  i tried my level best to explain my issue . please any one help me to resolve this issue.

Error Op

[Error Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G648z.jpg)

**My View Code**

```
 @Html.Label("Contact Person", new { @class = "control-label" })
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CustomerContactID, new SelectList(string.Empty, "Value", "Text"), "Please select a ContactPerson", new { @class = "form-control", type = "text", id = "CustomerContactID" })
  <button id="AddContactPerson">Add ContactPerson</button>
  <div id="AddNewContactPerson"></div>
```

**My j-query wrote in parent view**

```
    $(function () {
      $('#AddNewContactPerson').dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      width: 400,
      height:500,
      resizable: false,
      title: 'Add New',
      modal: true,
      open: function(event, ui) {
      $(this).load("@Url.Action("ContactPersonPartialView", "VisitorsForm")");
        },
        buttons: {
            "Close": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });

   $("#AddContactPerson").click(function () {
    $("#AddNewContactPerson").dialog("open");
    });
  });
```

**Controller Code**

```
 public ActionResult ContactPersonPartialView()
  {
      ViewBag.CustomerID = new SelectList(db.Customers, "CustomerID", "DisplayName");
      return View("ContactPersonPartialView");
  }
  [HttpPost]

  public JsonResult ContactPersonCreate(VisitorsViewModel VVviewmodel)
  {
      ViewBag.CustomerID = new SelectList(db.Customers, "CustomerID", "DisplayName", VVviewmodel.CustomerID);
      var ContactIDObj = Guid.NewGuid();
      var CustomerContactIDObj = Guid.NewGuid();

      var CustomerContactObj = new CustomerContact()
      {
          CustomerContactID = CustomerContactIDObj,
          CustomerID = VVviewmodel.CustomerID,
          ContactReference = VVviewmodel.ContactPerson,
          ContactID = ContactIDObj,
          IsActive = true,
          IsDeleted = false,
          CreatedDate = DateTime.Now,
          EditedDate = DateTime.Now,
          LastActiveOn = DateTime.Now,
          RowID = Guid.NewGuid(),
          CreatedSessionID = Guid.NewGuid(),
          EditedSessionID = Guid.NewGuid(),
          OfflineMode = false,
          OfflineID = Guid.NewGuid()
      };
      var ContactObj = new Contact()
      {
          ContactID = ContactIDObj,
          DisplayName = VVviewmodel.CustomerID.ToString(),
          PrintName = VVviewmodel.CustomerID.ToString(),
          Phone1 = VVviewmodel.PhoneNo,
          Mobile1 = VVviewmodel.MobileNo,
          Email1 = VVviewmodel.Email,
          Email2 = VVviewmodel.AlternateEmail

      };

      db.Contacts.Add(ContactObj);
      db.CustomerContacts.Add(CustomerContactObj);
      db.SaveChanges();
      ModelState.Clear();

      //return Json(new
      //{
      //    redirectUrl = Url.Action("create", "VisitorsForm"),
      //    isRedirect = true
      //});
      return Json("VisitorsForm", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
  }
```

I donno how to redirect to same pop-up window partial view  or to parent view please any one correct my redirect controller code.

**My Partial View Code**

```
  <div id="AddNewContactPerson">

    @Html.Label("Customer Name")
    @Html.DropDownList("CustomerID", "Select")

    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ContactPerson)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ContactPerson)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ContactPerson)

    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email)

    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AlternateEmail)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AlternateEmail)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AlternateEmail)

    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PhoneNo)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PhoneNo)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PhoneNo)

    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MobileNo)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MobileNo)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MobileNo)

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" onclick="SaveContact()" />
    </p>

   </div>
   </form>

  </fieldset>
  }

  <div>
  @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
  </div>
  <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.4-ui.min.js"></script>
  <link href="~/Content/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.24.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
   function SaveContact() {
    var CustomerName = $("#CustomerID").val();
    var ContactPerson = $("#ContactPerson").val();
    var Email = $("#Email").val();
    var AlternateEmail = $("#AlternateEmail").val();
    var PhoneNo = $("#PhoneNo").val();
    var MobileNo = $("#MobileNo").val();
    var CustomerContact = {
        "ContactPerson": ContactPerson, "Email": Email,
        "AlternateEmail": AlternateEmail, "PhoneNo": PhoneNo,
        "MobileNo": MobileNo, "CustomerID": CustomerName
    };

    $.post("/VisitorsForm/ContactPersonCreate", CustomerContact,
    function (data) { if (data == 0) { location = location.href; } }, 'json');
}
</script>
```

I posted my whole code here please any one check my code. In partial view the customer name will be null when i click create button and it didn't redirect correctly. i try my level best to explain my issue. please any one give solution for this problem.

Advance Thanks..

Comment: First of all remove type="submit". You are not submitting form. you are calling savecontact funtion on button click.

Answer (score 0):

For the 1 part of your question:

`CustomerName` is probably null, since you have no input with that name on your partial. You only have `@Html.DropDownList("CustomerID", "Select")` which will pass in your `CustomerID` only, not the `CustomerName`. But I don't think that is a huge problem, I suppose you'll store the ID in the database anyway.

If you need the name, you can probably simply get it from the database based on the `CustomerID` value.

The second part is not completely clear for me, what should be the condition which makes a different between the two windows to show?

Comment: Csaba my second question is if i enter the details and click the create button to save the details in db .if i click the create button either it have to stay in (show) the partial view popup window. if i click the close button in popup window it close the popup window or it have to redirect to parent view (Main View- Visitors Form) after click the create button in pop-up window.